# Launchd not launching ssh-agent after plist edit

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to reconfigure my ssh-agent to have a timeout via the -t argument.

I edited /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist

```
<array>
  <string>/usr/bin/ssh-agent</string>
  <string>-l</string>
  <string>-t</string>
  <string>300</string>
</array>
```

Then I issued

```
$ launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist
```

Followed by

```
$ launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/ord.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist
```

It seems to have loaded it back up.

```
$ launchctl list | grep ssh
-       0       org.openbsd.ssh-agent
```

But now it doesn't launch when I use a ssh key.  OpenSSH asks me for the passphrase instead of the GUI ssh-agent.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm trying to find a way to force OSX to ask for my ssh passphrase after 10mins but I can't even unload the plist to edit it - I see it: ````launchctl: Error unloading: org.openbsd.ssh-agent````

Comment: With the help of some Apple gurus, I figured this out: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26795372